# HP ProLiant DL160 Gen5 Virtualization

Tags: virtualization, xen, xenserver, xeon, intel-vt-x

we want to create some vm's on older server.
Its an HP ProLiant DL160 Gen5 with an Xeon 5405.
So by the intel specs (http://ark.intel.com/products/33079) the cpu included the VT-x technology. But there aren't any settings in the BIOS for VT-x.
It may be true that the bios not support vt-x but the cpu?

Greetings

Comment: Old BIOSes may refer to it as "Vanderpool". Check in Advanced - CPU Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a firmware upgrade.

See the following answer: [Flashing the BIOS on a DL380 G5 without Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/517287/flashing-the-bios-on-a-dl380-g5-without-windows/517289#517289)